# Moving Images from Photoshop to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, transparency, creative-cloud

I downloaded this very awesome set of iOS7 GUI components to use for building mockups for apps, found here: http://www.teehanlax.com/tools/iphone/.  I'm working in Illustrator but the file is a PSD.  I'm running both Ps and Ai simultaneously, and when I drag a component from the PSD into my Ai file, the transparency becomes white.  To be clear, I am literally dragging and dropping from Ps into Ai using the Move Tool which generally works.  What am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a work-around? Perhaps you can work in AI completely, opening the .psd file in AI, making sure that "convert to objects" is checked, and saving as an AI file. You can probably save it as a psd again if needed.

As far as I can tell, transparency when using the layer move tool isn't supported. If you use the path selection tool to use it to move from one program to the next, it kind of preserves the paths but just the path only. It just seems more practical to use AI in terms with workflow. It handles .psd files pretty well. Less CPU usage probably instead of having two programs open at the same time.